# getElementsByClassName doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get some event listeners to work, but for some reason they are not working properly.

The two event blocks below work fine on their own, but together only the `removes` block works. If I comment out that block, then the `users` block starts to work. What is causing this to happen?

```
var removes = document.getElementsByClassName("x");
for(var c in removes){
    removes[c].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("Remove");
    }, false);
}

var users = document.getElementsByClassName("user");
for(var i in users){
    users[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("Go");
    }, false);
}
```

Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<div class="user" data-id="123456">
    <div>
        <img id="avatar" src="http://example.com/photos/image.png" style="height: 50px;" alt="Avatar"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>My Username</h3>
        <p>example@example.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="x" data-id="123456">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you testing it on?

Comment: See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea). You're not even using it on an array. I'm convinced you get an exception from `removes[c].addEventListener`, breaking the rest of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getElementsByClassName returns a HTMLNodeList, which basicly is an Array of Nodes not an object on the form

```
{ "a": "b" }
```

So you don't use for ... in loops but a regular for

e.g.

```
for( var i = 0; i < removes.length; i++ ){
    removes[i].addEventListener( "click", function(){} );
}
```

Comment: Of course it's an object! (Everything is an object!)

Comment: I should have said it differently a HTMLNodeList is not an object on { "a": "c" } that you use for ... in loops on

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var c in removes)
```

will return you the properties of the HTMLNodeList.

For example:

If you run `for(var i in removes) { console.log(i)}` you will get

```
length 
item 
namedItem
```

So instead use

```
for( var i = 0; i < removes.length; i++ ){
    removes[i].addEventListener( "click", function(){console.log("Remove");
    }, false} );
}
```